# Разные стили ползунков слайдера jquery ui

Tags: jquery, ui

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста,как сделать разные стили для ползунков слайдера jquery ui?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI Slider рендерится в HTML как `<div class="ui-slider">` внутри которого растоложены элементы `<a class="ui-slider-handle">`, соответствующие ползункам.
Таким образом стилю ползунков соответствует CSS-селектор `.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle`

А если Вам нужно определить разные стили для разных ползунков - пройдитесь по коллекции ползунков слайдера и назначьте им собственные классы, например таким образом:

```
$('#id-слайдера .ui-slider-handle').each(function (index, handle) {
    if (index % 2 == 0) $(handle).addClass('even-handle');
    else $(handle).addClass('odd-handle);
});
```